# Grub Problem after installing Elementary OS 5.1

Tags: system-installation, boot, grub, release-hera

I install Elementary Os 5.1 in HP pavilion notebook. after installing HP Notebook enter grub rescue mode and does not find "error: file '/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found"

Answer (score 1):

After fresh Hera install and reboot, I can't boot and get same error:

> error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
>   Entering rescue mode...
>   grub rescue>

What I did to solve it:

- Boot again with USB install stick ("Try Elementary" option).
- From a terminal console, create the missing folder ( /boot/grub/i386-pc ) on the target disk.
- Install grub.

Something like this:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sda3  /mnt    ( in my case, /dev/sda3 is my root / partition ) 
$ sudo mkdir  /mnt/boot/grub/i386-pc  
$ sudo grub-install  --root-directory=/mnt    /dev/sda
```

reboot. That's all. Working.

Some info:

When installing, the wizard asked me to create an EFI partition. So, I tried WITHOUT and then WITH EFI partition. Either case, I get same error (I just keep a small partition in the first sectors of the disk, about 200MB, which I toggle from FAT32 to EFI type).

Credits to https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207827

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

tray boot-repair-disk https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

or super-grub-disk